# run junit only for specific microservice

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline, microservices

We have around 15 microservices in a repo. While creating PR, all the 15 microservices are running their junits. Is it possible to run only the specific microservice's junit? we are using gradle tool and jenkins pipeline.

for example :
Microservices : A,B,C,D

Changes done only in C ,

Expecting : only C microservice's junit to run from jenkins

*not A,B and D.*

Comment: Wouldn't every microservice have its own git repo? So different jenkins pipeline for each microservice.

Comment: sadly no. only one pipeline for all the services.

Comment: Ok, strange. Have you tried creating a separate stage for each microservice and executing only the relavent one when needed like in the above case only C microservice's stage?

Comment: all I want to know is how to find the service where changes have been made and how to execute only the specific service ? saw some features like "dir" in jenkins but dint get any idea how to proceed further

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that could work for you. Somehow you have to know which change happened on which microservice. This could be done by naming the branches after a specific template.

```
isDMicroservice = "${BRANCH_NAME}" ==~ /^feature/D/*/
```

so: `feature/{microservice}/...` could be a template to differ between the microservices.

This would allow you to seperate the changes by parsing the Git branches.
You could then execute only specific Jenkins stages:

```
        stage('D Microservice') {
        when {
            return isDMicroservice
          }
        steps {
            script {
               dir("d-microservice") {
                // Go into the folder of D
                // junit ... 
               }
            }
          }
        }
```

This solution works but I would probably split out the microservices into single repositories, each having its own Jenkinsfile. I know this is probably not what you want to do but this will save you A LOT of trouble later on.

---

Another solution is using a [when { changeset(...) }](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when).

```
    stage('D Microservice') {
      when {
        changeset "**/D/*.*"
      }
```

Usually the stage should only be execute on file changes in microservice D.

Comment: hey thanks.. let me try this and update you. am looking for single repo and single jenkinsfile solution. will keep you posted. Thanks again

Comment: I updated the answer. Maybe you are better of with the changeset.